# How do I count distinct combinations of column values?

Tags: sqlite

I use SQLite to log every user's every access to my server. Every time a user uses a function, I append a record to the database.

The database looks like:

```
usr_id  fun_id
3       1       // user_3 used function_1
2       13      // user_2 used function_13
3       11      // user_3 used function_11
2       1       // user_2 used function_1
7       2       // ...
```

`usr_id` stands for a user, `fun_id` stands for functions like login / send_text / logout...

I want to know each function's usage, used by who and how many times, to plot with gnuplot. In short, I need this for plotting:

```
fun_id  usr_id  used_count  
1       2       1           // user_2 used function_1 once
1       3       1           // user_3 used function_1 once
2       7       1           // user_7 used function_2 once
13      2       3           // user_2 used function_13 three times
```

How to generate this with a SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `count(*)` along with a grouping:

```
select fun_id, usr_id, count(*) as used_count
from tablename
group by fun_id, usr_id
order by fun_id, usr_id;
```

Comment: That's it, I didn't know `group by` and `order by` support multiple column. Thanks.

Comment: What if you want to group by one set of columns and within these count another set of columns? `count(distinct b1,b2,b3) from table group by a1,a2,a3` does not work.

Comment: I'd suggest you [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that as a separate question -- include sample data, desired results, and what's wrong with the queries you've tried.